# Remove object based on a key from array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object, key-value

Below is the json :

```
var data= {
    'A' : {
        'Total' : 123,
        'Cricket' : 76,
        'Football' : 12,
        'Hockey' : 1,
        'None' : 10
    },
    'B' : {
        'Total': 123,
        'Cricket': 76,
        'Football': 12,
        'Hockey': 1,
        'None': 10
    },
    'C' : {
        'Total': 0,
        'Cricket': 76,
        'Football': 12,
        'Hockey': 1,
        'None': 10
    }   
}
```

I want to remove C in which value of total is zero,,

```
$.each(json, function (key, value) {
    if (value.Total === 0) {
        //delete
    }
});
```

I have tried various ways but didnt work

Comment: use `delete json[key]`. It will delete that object.

Comment: really? `delete[key]` ? are you sure of that syntax?

Comment: by the way, that's not JSON, that's just a javascript object, if it were JSON, you'd have to JSON.parse it before doing anything more

Comment: More so, it's not an array of objects either.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-do-i-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-do-i-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove a property from a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-do-i-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object)

Comment: This is not an array but an object. An array would use rectangular brackets: `var x=[1, '2', 3+''];`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) keyword to delete a property in an object.

```js
var json = {
  'A': {
    'Total': 123,
    'Cricket': 76,
    'Football': 12,
    'Hockey': 1,
    'None': 10

  },
  'B': {
    'Total': 123,
    'Cricket': 76,
    'Football': 12,
    'Hockey': 1,
    'None': 10
  },
  'C': {
    'Total': 0,
    'Cricket': 76,
    'Football': 12,
    'Hockey': 1,
    'None': 10
  }
}

$.each(json, function(key, value) {
  if (value.Total === 0) {
    delete json[key];
  }
});

console.log(json);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){


var data=    {
        'A' : {
            'Total' : 123,
            'Cricket' : 76,
            'Football' : 12,
            'Hockey' : 1,
            'None' : 10

        },
    'B' : {
        'Total': 123,
        'Cricket': 76,
        'Football': 12,
        'Hockey': 1,
        'None': 10
    },
    'C' : {
        'Total': 0,
        'Cricket': 76,
        'Football': 12,
        'Hockey': 1,
        'None': 10
    }   
}

 $.each(data, function (key, value) {

              if (value.Total === 0) {
                 delete data[key];
              }
});

console.log(data);

});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ef3Le1en/